# Passing property as parameter

Tags: c#

I am creating a merit function calculator, which for the uninitiated takes a selection of properties, and calculates a value based on how close those properties are to some idealized values (the merit function). This then enables the user to find an item that most closely matches their requirements.

This is the code I'd like to use:

```
public class MeritFunctionLine
{
    public Func<CalculationOutput, double> property { get; set; }
    public double value { get; set; }
    public ComparisonTypes ComparisonType { get; set; }
}

public class MeritFunction
{
    public List<MeritFunctionLine> Lines { get; set; }
    public double Calculate(CalculationOutput values)
    {
        double m = 0;
        foreach (var item in Lines)
        {
            m += Math.Abs(values.property - item.value);
        }
        return m;
    }
}

public class CalculationOutput
{
    public double property1 { get; set; }
    public double property2 { get; set; }
    public double property3 { get; set; }
    public double property4 { get; set; }
}
```

Obviously this doesn't compile as *values* doesn't contain a member called *property*, but here is an explanation of what I want to do:

1. Create a new MeritFunction
2. Add an arbitrary number of MeritFunctionLines to MeritFunction.Lines
3. The MeritFunctionLine.property should specify what property of CalculationOutput should be compared in MeritFunction.Calculate

i.e.

```
MeritFunction mf = new MeritFunction();
mf.Lines.Add(new MeritFunctionLine() { property = x => x.Property1, value = 90, comparisonType = ComparisonTypes.GreaterThan });
mf.Lines.Add(new MeritFunctionLine() { property = x => x.Property3, value = 50, comparisonType = ComparisonTypes.Equals });

CalculationOutput c1 = new CalculationOutput() { property1 = 1, property2 = 20, property3 = 150, property4 = 500 };
CalculationOutput c2 = new CalculationOutput() { property1 = 15, property2 = 32, property3 = 15, property4 = 45 };

double value1 = mf.Calculate(c1);
double value2 = mf.Calculate(c2);
```

I am not asking how to pass a property as a parameter into a function, which is prohibited by C#.

Comment: Hey, this is prohibited in C#! :)

Comment: I don't quite see the issue - if you use `m += Math.Abs(item.property(values) - item.value);` in your `foreach` loop it should work fine as far as I understand what you're trying to do...

Comment: If there are only 4 properties, a switch statement may be easiest thing to introduce. Other thing I can think of is a dictionary of properties in Calculation output

Comment: @Sayse unfortunately not, there are many hundreds of properties, and I would also like to use this with other classes

Comment: @MarcelN. thanks for reading to the end of the post :)

Comment: It's not clear what you want to do with the `comparisonType`

Comment: @sWW inside the foreach loop I will have different behaviour based on the comparison type, I've just left it out for the moment for brevity

Comment: @Nick in that case I think Mendo42's comment should set you in good stead.

Comment: @Medo42 excellent that is exactly what I was looking for, if you post an answer I'll mark it as such.

Comment: @Nick, I expanded my answer quite a bit - not sure if you get a notification about that if I don't ping you.

Comment: @Medo42 thanks for that, the last step for me was to generify it!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You almost have the right solution already - the only missing piece is how you use the `MeritFunctionLine.property` property to get the desired value from the `CalculationOutput`.

In your `foreach` loop, simply replace the calculation line with

```
m += Math.Abs(item.property(values) - item.value);
```

**Edit:**

**Adding Genericity**

To address Obsidian Phoenix's comment, you can use this with different classes by making both `MeritFunction` and `MeritFunctionLine` generic, so:

```
public class MeritFunctionLine<TCalcOutput>
{
    public Func<TCalcOutput, double> property { get; set; }
    public double value { get; set; }
    public ComparisonTypes ComparisonType { get; set; }
}

public class MeritFunction<TCalcOutput>
{
    public List<MeritFunctionLine<TCalcOutput>> Lines { get; set; }
    public double Calculate(TCalcOutput values)
    {
        double m = 0;
        foreach (var item in Lines)
        {
            m += Math.Abs(item.property(values) - item.value);
        }
        return m;
    }
}
```

The rewritten usage example would be

```
MeritFunction<CalculationOutput> mf = new MeritFunction<CalculationOutput>();
mf.Lines.Add(new MeritFunctionLine<CalculationOutput>() { property = x => x.Property1, value = 90, comparisonType = ComparisonTypes.GreaterThan });
mf.Lines.Add(new MeritFunctionLine<CalculationOutput>() { property = x => x.Property3, value = 50, comparisonType = ComparisonTypes.Equals });

CalculationOutput c1 = new CalculationOutput() { property1 = 1, property2 = 20, property3 = 150, property4 = 500 };
CalculationOutput c2 = new CalculationOutput() { property1 = 15, property2 = 32, property3 = 15, property4 = 45 };

double value1 = mf.Calculate(c1);
double value2 = mf.Calculate(c2);
```

**Some extra convenience**

If you have many `MeritFunctionLine`s to add, the syntax above can be a bit tedious. So as a bonus, let's change `MeritFunction` so that it can be initialized with the list initialization syntax. To do that, we need to make it `IEnumerable` and give it an `Add` function:

```
public class MeritFunction<TCalcOutput> : IEnumerable<MeritFunctionLine<TCalcOutput>>
{
    public List<MeritFunctionLine<TCalcOutput>> Lines { get; set; }

    public MeritFunction()
    {
        Lines = new List<MeritFunctionLine<TCalcOutput>>();
    }

    public void Add(Func<TCalcOutput, double> property, ComparisonTypes ComparisonType, double value)
    {
        Lines.Add(new MeritFunctionLine<CalculationOutput>
        {
            property = property,
            value = value,
            comparisonType = ComparisonType
        });
    }

    public double Calculate(TCalcOutput values)
    {
        double m = 0;
        foreach (var item in Lines)
        {
            m += Math.Abs(item.property(values) - item.value);
        }
        return m;
    }

    public IEnumerator<MeritFunctionLine<TCalcOutput>> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return List.GetEnumerator();
    }

    System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return this.GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

Note that the `Add` method receives the parameters in a different order - you'll understand why when you look at the usage. Quite a bit of extra code, but now creating our `MeritFunction` is a bit nicer:

```
MeritFunction<CalculationOutput> mf = new MeritFunction<CalculationOutput>
{
    { x => x.Property1, ComparisonTypes.GreaterThan, 90 },
    { x => x.Property3, ComparisonTypes.Equals,      50 }
};
```

Note, all code untested. Use at own risk :)

Comment: Thats definitely a lot neater than my example, how would you extend the code if (according to the comments) the OP wanted to use this for a variety of different classes?

Comment: Ah nice update. Exactly what I was about to update my answer to. ;)

Comment: I felt like adding a bit of bonus :)

Comment: I particularly like the implementation of IEnumerable - a sensible addition

Comment: That's a requirement for making the list initializer syntax work.

Answer (score 4):

It is possible, but it's not exactly pretty. You can make use of `Expression<Func<double>>` to pass in the property, then use reflection to pull the value back out.

**NB:** I have not coded this to accomodate for error scenarios, you may want to add additional checks.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MeritFunction<CalculationOutput> mf = new MeritFunction<CalculationOutput>();

        //Create an instance of the object for reference.
        var obj = new CalculationOutput();

        //Use Lambda to set the Property Expression on the Line, pointing at the Property we are interested in.
        mf.Lines.Add(new MeritFunctionLine() { PropertyExpression = () => obj.property1, value = 90, ComparisonType = ComparisonTypes.GreaterThan });
        mf.Lines.Add(new MeritFunctionLine() { PropertyExpression = () => obj.property3, value = 50, ComparisonType = ComparisonTypes.Equals });

        CalculationOutput c1 = new CalculationOutput() { property1 = 1, property2 = 20, property3 = 150, property4 = 500 };
        CalculationOutput c2 = new CalculationOutput() { property1 = 15, property2 = 32, property3 = 15, property4 = 45 };

        double value1 = mf.Calculate(c1);
        double value2 = mf.Calculate(c2);

        Console.WriteLine(value1);
        Console.WriteLine(value2);
    }
}

public class MeritFunctionLine
{
    //Capture an expression representing the property we want.
    public Expression<Func<double>> PropertyExpression { get; set; }

    public double value { get; set; }
    public ComparisonTypes ComparisonType { get; set; }
}

public class MeritFunction<T>
{
    public List<MeritFunctionLine> Lines { get; set; }

    public MeritFunction()
    {
        Lines = new List<MeritFunctionLine>();
    }

    public double Calculate(T values)
    {
        double m = 0;
        foreach (var item in Lines)
        {
            //Get the Value before calculating.
            double value = ExtractPropertyValue(item, values);

            m += Math.Abs(value - item.value);
        }
        return m;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Take the Provided Expression representing the property, and use it to extract the property value from the object we're interested in.
    /// </summary>
    private double ExtractPropertyValue(MeritFunctionLine line, T values)
    {
        var expression = line.PropertyExpression.Body as MemberExpression;
        var prop = expression.Member as PropertyInfo;

        double value = (double)prop.GetValue(values);

        return value;
    }
}

public class CalculationOutput
{
    public double property1 { get; set; }
    public double property2 { get; set; }
    public double property3 { get; set; }
    public double property4 { get; set; }
}

public enum ComparisonTypes
{
    GreaterThan,
    Equals
}
```

The one gotcha of this method, is that you need to create an instance of the object whilst building up the Lines property, otherwise you can't actually access the property through the lambda.

If you only need this for a single class, then this is likely overkill, but it will work with essentially any class.